# How to post an array value in JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I want to post an array value in JSON.

Below is my code :

```
-(void)getConnection {

    NSArray *comment=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"hello,yes,tell", nil];

    NSURL *aurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sajalaya.com/taskblazer/staffend/form/iphonearraytest.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:comment options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
   NSString *new = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 // NSString *new = [comment JSONString];

 // NSArray *new=[comment jsonvalue];

    NSString *postString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tag=&comment=%@&total=%@",new,@"4"];

    NSLog(@"this is post string%@",postString);
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];       
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know your question, but my answer is short and simple. You should use great open source library for this, which is: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), and do request like this:

```
_httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://sajalaya.com"]];

[_httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:comment options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *new = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        new, @"comment",
                        @4, @"total,
                        nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                             path:@"/taskblazer/staffend/form/iphonearraytest.php"
                                                       parameters:params];
request.timeoutInterval = 8;

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
      // success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      // failure
}];
```

Comment: but i am using json framework .....lets take the example means i have to send an array value and i am sending but in back end he is not getting array ...he is getting like an string ...i got stuck in this case ...pls any one give me best option

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following Mutable Array Operation `componentsJoinedByString`.

**e.g.**

```
NSMutableArray *commennts=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"hello,yes,tell", nil];

NSString* strCommentsJoin = [commennts componentsJoinedByString:@","]; // Please use your separator
```

Comment: i want to send json array to php link but in php side it is getting like string ,but i have to send array and he should get it like array form,,,,,,thanks for ur reply

Comment: PHP/.net/Java also have same functionality to separate the string elements to array